# How to extract specific value from a table and add it to another one based a dropdown value

Tags: google-sheets

I want to retrieve data from table like this

|  | dépot | retrait |
| --- | --- | --- |
| binance USDT | 1.043 | 1.039 |
| PM | 1.028 | 1.030 |

and select data from it based on criteria of the second table like so:

| type de transaction | wallet | Montant envoyé |
| --- | --- | --- |
| deposit | USDT | **1.043** |

where the highlighted `1.043` is the value I want to retrieve based on the input `deposit` and `USDT`.

The cells for `deposit` and `USDT` are supposed to contain dropdown menus. So, if I change the dropdown selection, I want the data retrieved to be changed accordingly. How can I do that?

[This is the example sheet I am building.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PIk8NHAvGLYEaRXaQfUENwxruXjUn92y5uwGHZkD40U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Since answers to Google Sheets questions will always have reference to cells and ranges, your question would be much better served if it contains a sample sheet, preferably editable. That way, answers can directly refer to contents in your example using ranges. Moreover, if your text example misses meaningful features of your sample sheet, others can point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX-XMATCH-XMATCH`

```cpp
=INDEX(B2:C3,XMATCH(A7,B1:C1),XMATCH(B7,A2:A3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) twice - once horizontally and once vertically.

For example,

```js
=filter(filter(B2:C,B2:C2="deposit"),A2:A="USDT")
```

Answer (score 1):

Even `SUMPRODUCT` will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:C1=E2)*(A2:A=F2)*(B2:C))
```

[image]